# How to get request header values in symfony

Tags: symfony, http-headers, httpwebrequest

Am using symfony frame work in my application to make rest web service. I want to get request header values in controller method. Is there any way to achieve it.

Comment: What do you mean by "request header values"? GET values? POST values? HTTP Headers?

Comment: I mean HTTP Headers .

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to pass your Request object to the controller method and then in controller use `$request->headers->all()`

For example:

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $headers = $request->headers->all();
}
```

You can also get Request object from a controller by calling `$this->getRequest()` from controller method.

Comment: `getRequest()` was deprecated in 2.4. You need to pass request in the method parameters.

Answer (score 14):

If you need to get a specific header you can use:

```
$request->headers->get('My-Header');
```

See documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-accept-headers-data

Answer (score -1):

If You want header type `$request->getMethod` just like in forms this will git you `POST|GET|PUT|DELETE` request method